# How to launch once instance of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having a scenario. I am trying to lock my application using an `PinActivity` which I created. I am running a service which has a counter timer for 5mins. If there is no activity by the user in app for 5 mins. I will show him the PINActivity which he has to unlock and enter the app. I am launching the `PINActivity` like this:

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, PINActivity.class);
loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(loginIntent);
```

So when the user comes back to the app and see the `PINActivity` he will unlock it and enter the app. But what if the user doesn't enter the PIN and leave the app again ideal for more then 5 mins(Note: my service starts the counter timer the moment user brings the app to foreground). I don't want to add multiple instance of the same `PINActivity` at top. How can I make sure I have only one `PINActivity` at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. This will prevent Android from launching `PINActivity` if there is already an instance of `PINActivity` on top of the stack.

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, PINActivity.class);
loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(loginIntent);
```

Please don't try to use special launch modes like `singleTask` or `singleInstance` as others have suggested. This won't help and will complicate the problem for you.

You can specify `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest entry for `PINActivity` as well. This has the same effect as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Answer (score 1):

Add **launchMode="singleInstance"** in your activity in manifest like this:

```
  <activity
   android:launchMode="singleInstance"
   android:name=".MainActivity"
                         ..... />
```

Comment: Still two PinActivity instance are stacking over each other. When I press back I get one more `PINActivity`

Comment: `singleInstance` isn't the correct approach. OP wants to put an `Activity` on top of his other activities. `singleInstance` launch mode is only used to control the root `Activity` in a task.

Answer (score 1):

add   `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: `singleInstance` isn't the correct approach. OP wants to put an `Activity` on top of his other activities. `singleInstance` launch mode is only used to control the root `Activity` in a task.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch activity you can use this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

If activity is already there then it will use the same instance else create new one and no duplication will be there.

Comment: Still two PinActivity instance are stacking over each other. When I press back I get one more `PINActivity`

Comment: can't you check getActivity() instance of MyActivity in your timer...as your MyActivity is already running then it will provide you context of your current activity

Comment: `REORDER_TO_FRONT` should work. You shouldn't get 2 instances of the `Activity` in this case. There must be something else funny going on.

Answer (score 0):

> In manifest add attribute of singleInstance in activity tag.

```
<activity 
    android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

[Click Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: I dont want to remove all activities. Only if PINActivity exists at top of the stack.

Comment: `singleInstance` isn't the correct approach. OP wants to put an `Activity` on top of his other activities. `singleInstance` launch mode is only used to control the root `Activity` in a task.